# how can i store font family into an array and use it in select options in react.js

Tags: reactjs, canvas, react-select, select-options

Actually, I want an array of font family so that I can use it in select options. On the basis of select options I want to change the font of text input field.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";



const styles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman"
  }),
  menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman"
  })
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select className="select" styles={styles}  >
     <option> Times Roman </option>
</Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Okay, the code is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the selected font in the state, then pass the state in the styles.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";



const styles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontFamily: stateStyle
  }),
  menu: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontFamily: stateStyle
  })
};

function App() {
const [stateStyle,setStateStyle] = useState("some font")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select className="select" styles={styles}  >
     <option onChange={() => setStateStyle("Times New Roman")}> Times Roman </option>
</Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```